# Не могу найти аппарат и связаться с ним

Tags: linux, драйвер

Не могу понять как "соединиться" с аппаратом и начать "общение" с ним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
comp@comp0:~$ lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:e8e9 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0403 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
  idProduct          0xe8e9 
  bcdDevice            7.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           55
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

Сам аппарат есть, `Port 2 : Dev 13` либо `Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0403:e8e9 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd` , драйверов на него нет, как и ПО, как мне начать с ним "говорить"?

Также я не совсем понял где он находится "аппарат" ака файл.

---

*Подскажите книги для написания драйверов и подключения аппаратов к линуксу*

Comment: Что за аппарат то? Ищите на www.ftdichip.com информацию по линукс-драйверам. Ваш случай наверное в `Technical Note TN_101`

Comment: @PavelGridin да это аппарат, по USB "квадратному " подключается. Просто печально что по КОМ порту аппарат сразу видит и создает папку и файл , а тут файла я как то и не увидел , типо " не создаётся "

Comment: честно говоря ничего не понятно, по какому КОМ? по VCP? какая папка и файл,  в какой ОС создаётся?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте libusb

Comment: Вы хотя бы вывод `lsusb -v` выложите. Вообще ничего не понятно, о чём речь.

Comment: @0andriy добавил

Comment: @PavelGridin а что надо сделать чтоб можно было работать с аппаратом ???  Просто не понятно зашёл я на `www.ftdichip.com` , а дальше что делать ??

Comment: Пишите производителю письмо и выясняйте. Там всё кастомное, судя по выводу. Без даташита на устройство ничего не сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Возьми например https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1

На вашем устройсве 2 интерфейса (порта). В них 4 эндпоинта - 2 входа, 2 выхода.

Говорить с устройством просто:

Подключение

```
import usb1
with usb1.USBContext() as context:
    handle = context.openByVendorIDAndProductID(
        0x0403,
        0xe8e9,
        skip_on_error=True,
    )
    if handle is None:
        # Устройство не подключилось - выводите ошибку.
    with handle.claimInterface(INTERFACE):
        # В этом блоке выполняете свои задачи.
```

Чтение

```
data = handle.bulkRead(ENDPOINT, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Запись

```
handle.bulkWrite(ENDPOINT, data)
```

Comment: Да , если знаешь питон и комп не может его поддерживать, а если на компе только gcc да место пару гигов то куда деваться ?? Да и прыгать с языка на язык весьма сложно если ты один. Но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: libusb это сишная библиотека. Эндпоинты читаются и пишутся также, только синтаксис другой

Comment: У меня умещается сишно питонский комбаин с графикой и анимашками на 600 мегабайт жесткого диска. Это ещё без зачистки ненужного